# Why Collapsed by accident after setInterval ajax call load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with all element with collapsed-out after ajax-call-load in setInterval executed immediately all collapsed-out became collapsed-in automatically.
It should be kept collapsed-out if not command to collapse-in

Any idea ?

Note: I've been test by disabling ajax-call-load in setInterval and all collapsed-out not become collapsed-in. Bootstrap 2.3.2

```
Example:
<div id="totalmessage"></div>
<div id="totalmessage1"></div>
<div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collout" class="btn btn-small">expand</div>

<div id="postdata">Click to Post</div>

<div class="collapse out" id="collout">
My collapsed out data and refreshed after postdata clicked
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#postdata').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "/comments.php?jfocode=add&ajax=true",
                    data : { content : 1234 },
                    success : function(data) {
                             //reload data seamesly
                             $('#collout').html(data);
                    }
      });
      return false;
});

setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url : '/message.php',
            data : 'jfocode=getmsgcount&location=INBOX&status=NEW&ajax=true',
            success : function(data) {
                $('#totalmessage').ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
                    if (data.totalmessage)
                    {
                        $('#totalmessage').html(data.totalmessage);
                        $('#totalmessage1').html(data.totalmessage);
                        if (data.totalmessage > 0)
                        {
                            $('#totalmessage').show();
                            $('#totalmessage1').show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#totalmessage').hide();
                            $('#totalmessage1').hide();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    }, 10000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using   event.stopPropagation(); after a successful ajax call to prevent the collapsable from "collapsing-in"

Comment: e.stopPropagation(); in #postdata click after ajax success does not help.

Comment: I found the problem and fixed.
The problem is ajaxComplete, no need use this as ajaxComplete will reload everything